# Adding business logic before every spring async execution

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I've got a session info object on a thread local and I want to pass it to async job so the user details and etc. will be passed with details of the user initiate the async job.
I think I've spotted the place I need to override in order to add this functionality in a generic way: Extending the AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor class with overriding the "invoke" method from its parent (AsyncExecutionInterceptor) so the callable's call method will do some initialize on the new thread local side with original session info.

The issue is that I'm looking for good way to initalize the AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor with my version for "AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor". 
I've seen the "ProxyAsyncConfiguration" which initialize the AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. Can I supply an alternative implementation?

Is there a simple way of doing my original goal?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I looking for something similar with request scoped data.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to override AsyncConfigurer  which control the exception handler and executor however, to further fine control it does not allow you to AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor, if we have a way to dynamically return the executor qualifier we can serialize all the execution for specific runtime identifier. For example tradeId processing to same executor. This tradeId information is available only on run time.